# How do you unit test that methods such as ok() were called in aurelia-dialog using jasmine?

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-dialog

How do I go about unit testing a method that calls the DialogController? I want to test that `this.controller.ok()` was called.

`ReprocessLotDialog.js`

```
@inject(DialogController)
export class ReprocessLotDialog {
    constructor(dialogController) {
        this.controller = dialogController;
    }


    commitReprocessingLot() {    
        this.controller.ok({
            reprocessLot: this.model
        });
    }    

    commitIncompleteBags(){
       ... do stuff ....
       this.commitReprocessingLot();
    }
}
```

`myDialog.spec.js` I've tried this but can't get it to work

```
describe("The ReprocessLotDialog module", ()=> {
    let sut;

    beforeEach(()=> {
        var container = new Container().makeGlobal();
        container.registerInstance(DialogController,controller => new DialogController());
        sut = container.get(ReprocessLotDialog);
    });


     it("commitReprocessingLot() should call controller.ok", (done)=> {    
        spyOn(sut, "controller.ok");

        sut.commitIncompleteBags();
        expect(sut.controller.ok).toHaveBeenCalled();
        done();
    });
});
```

The test fails with `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.controller.ok({ reprocessLot: this.model })')`

As far as I understand it I'm passing the `DialogController` through DI into the `container` and `container.get(ReprocessLotDialog)` injects the DialogController into the ctor.

I've also tried 
`container.registerInstance(DialogController,{"dialogController":DialogController});` but that doesn't work either.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your unit tests shouldn't be utilizing the DI container. You simply new up an instance of `ReprocessLotDialog` and pass in a mock of `DialogController` that you created. If you're using Jasmine, it would look something like this:

```
describe("The ReprocessLotDialog module", ()=> {
 it("commitReprocessingLot() should call controller.ok", ()=> {    
    let dialogController = {
          ok: (arg) = { }
        };

    spyOn(dialogController, "ok");

    let sut = new ReprocessLotDialog(dialogController);

    sut.commitIncompleteBags();
    expect(dialogController.ok).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

You might also want to consider if testing if you shouldn't just be testing if `commitReprocessingLot` has been called instead of checking that it calls the method that's the only thing it does (at least in your example).

```
describe("The ReprocessLotDialog module", ()=> {
 it("commitReprocessingLot() should call controller.ok", ()=> {    
    let dialogController = {
          ok: (arg) = { }
        };

    let sut = new ReprocessLotDialog(dialogController);

    spyOn(sut, "commitReprocessingLot");

    sut.commitIncompleteBags();
    expect(su.commitReprocessingLot).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Both your and Patrick's answers were so helpful! I thought it was obligatory to use the DI when testing.
Is there any documentation on the best practices for testing in aurelia?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely stub out the controller or you can just spy on the instance method like this -

```
describe("The ReprocessLotDialog module", ()=> {
    let container;
    let sut;
    let controller;

    beforeEach(()=> {
        container = new Container().makeGlobal();
        controller = container.get(DialogController);
        sut = container.get(ReprocessLotDialog);
    });


     it("commitReprocessingLot() should call controller.ok", (done)=> {    
        spyOn(controller, 'ok');
        sut.commitIncompleteBags();
        expect(controller.ok).toHaveBeenCalled();
        done();
    });
});
```

Basically you should be able to create an instance in your container of the controller that will get passed in and you can spyOn the method directly on the instance.